# I can't change my parent user in my chat profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, profile-page

Given that the [Programmers' moderator elections](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election) are underway and I haven't decided whether to stand or not I thought I ought to change my parent user on https://chat.stackexchange.com to be my Web Applications account (so I'd still be allowed into the Teacher's Lounge!).

I click the "change" link and get a list of all sites I have accounts - so far so good.

I click on the Web Applications link and the page gets redrawn, but the parent user field is still set to Programmers'.

I just tried changing it to Stack Overflow but it still shows Programmers' in my profile. However, now I get Access Denied when I try and access the Teachers Lounge - so something's changed. I've managed to get back in, but it seems to be displaying Programmers' regardless of the account I actually pick.

Comment: Have you tried doing it after leaving all rooms? It might be, despite the diamond, forbidding you from doing it under the guise of stopping you from losing room access. It probably won't help, but it never hurts to try things new. Also, try changing to a non-diamond profile, then to Web Apps.

Comment: @Grace - I thought I had, though only by virtue of closing all the tabs (in Chrome) where I was in chat. Just trying again, but no it didn't work. Neither did changing it to Stack Overflow. Seems I'm stuck with it as Programmers'. I'll have to nominate myself now!

Comment: Hm... upon testing with myself, it's only not updating the little Favicon. If I change to my other profiles, my Gravatar and badge will change, as well as losing access. So the profile is definitely changing. But the Favicon stays with Gaming. For you, of course, it's not so easily apparent since you have the same gravatar everywhere. Not sure why it's latched onto Programmers for you, though.

Comment: @Grace - The link to the parent profile always points to Programmers' though too.

Comment: Hah, I didn't notice that was a link. Yeah, that's not changing, either. It like it's updating what Chat believes to be your parent profile (hence the badges and gravatar and access privileges), but your chat profile isn't actually updating with the correct profile (and thus the favicon and the accompanying link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, we recently introduced a bug that caused chat to always pick the same parent account (the first one when sorted by moderator status, then reputation), regardless of the one you chose.

That's fixed now.